# How to use custom 'doclet' in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, doclet

it's my `custom doclet` in the `eclipse`:

```
javadoc -doclet BADoclet -docletpath E:\Desktop2016\Part1\Tools -b4atarget "E:\AndroidStudioProjects\LibraryWrapper\recyclerview_aar\build\outputs\aar\aa.xml"
```

now how to edit and use this `doclet` in android studio ?

[Picture of 'Generate JavaDoc' in the android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn6Vi.png)

Comment: Does anybody have an answer to this?